# How can I maintain a one pointer gesture when explore-by-touch is enabled?

Tags: android, accessibility, android-view, talkback

I have a custom view that captures the user's signature ([John Hancock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hancock_%28disambiguation%29)). I want our application to be as accessible as possible, so I'm taking special care to ensure to optimize our screens for *TalkBack* and *Explore-by-Touch*. Since *Explore-by-Touch* changes all one finger gestures into two finger gestures, it breaks the custom signature view.

What I'd like to do is have *Explore-by-Touch* announce the view's content description on hover, then enable the view when the user double-taps. This will allow them to draw on top of the view with a single pointer like a normal user.

I've searched around but it's difficult to find detailed documentation on the Android accessibility libraries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When Explore by Touch is turned on, single-finger touch events are converted into hover events. You can watch these events by adding an [OnHoverListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnHoverListener.html) to your view or overriding [View.onHoverEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onHoverEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Once you're intercepting these events, you can usually just pass them to your normal touch handling code and map from hover actions to touch actions (as below).

```
@Override
public boolean onHoverEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mAccessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
        return onTouchEvent(event);
    } else {
        return super.onHoverEvent(event);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
            return handleDown(event);
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
            return handleMove(event);
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
            return handleUp(event);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a try.

Comment: Seems to work. There is a little lag on the first hover event, but it's not a huge deal.

Comment: This answer solved my big problem discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35165206/2813238 Big Thanks!